# Java,MySQL - NULL resultset

Tags: java, mysql

I got a method to get an integer from a MySQL table

```
public int getAddressID(String postcode) throws SQLException {
    String q = "SELECT PK_ADDRESS_ID FROM tbl_addresses WHERE postcode =" + "\"" + postcode + "\"";
    System.out.println(q);
    ResultSet rs = executeSearch(q);
    int pc = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String str = rs.getString("postcode");
        pc = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    System.out.println(pc);
    return pc;
}
```

The query seems fine but somehow when I initialize some variable and use this method, I get the error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`. Am I missing anything? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the value of postcode?

Comment: The idea is input a postcode and then find ADDRESS_ID. postcode value is unique.

Comment: if your return address_id value is not digit you can't convert to int.

Comment: @Ye Win: I think this points into the right direction. getString("postcode") tries to read postcode, but the query does not return it.

Comment: I saw Scary Wombat answer and yes, it's because of it.

Comment: NOTE: Use a preparedStatement if you receive the postcode from an input. You are open to injection inserting a String like this into the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is `SELECT PK_ADDRESS_ID ...`

but then you try to get

```
rs.getString("postcode");
```

change to

```
rs.getString("PK_ADDRESS_ID");
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are selecting PK_ADDRESS_ID column from the database and the value returned is either "" `(empty)` or `NULL`. So it shows `NumberFormatException` which cannot be converted as a Number.

So please check the value you get from the database.